# Importing nested name-value pairs from json into SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016, open-json

I am importing a json file into SQL 2016 which has some nested name-value pairs in a nested values structure. It's the values from these pairs I am having problems with, such as .

```
{ "name": "Colour", "value": "Orange" }, { "name": "Calories", "value": "25" }
```

sql:

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max)
SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\temp\fruit.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j

If (ISJSON(@JSON)=1) BEGIN
    Select * from openjson ( @JSON )
    WITH(
        id int,
        fruit varchar(20),
        Colour varchar(20) '$.values.Colour',
        Weight int '$.values.Weight'
    ) as Orders
END
ELSE
  Select 'JSON is invalid!'
```

and the results of which are:

```
id  fruit   Colour  Weight
1   orange  NULL    NULL
23  Banana  NULL    NULL
```

full (test) data..

[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "fruit": "orange",
      "values": [
        { "name": "Colour", "value": "Orange" },
        { "name": "Weight", "value": "16" },
        { "name": "Calories", "value": "25" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 23,
      "fruit": "Banana",
      "values": [
        { "name": "Colour", "value": "Yellow" },
        { "name": "Weight", "value": "30" },
        { "name": "Calories", "value": "250" }
      ]
    }
  ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try with next approach, which will return full data:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
SET @json = N'[ { "id": 1, "fruit": "orange", "values": [ { "name": "Colour", "value": "Orange" }, { "name": "Weight", "value": "16" }, { "name": "Calories", "value": "25" } ] }, { "id": 23, "fruit": "Banana", "values": [ { "name": "Colour", "value": "Yellow" }, { "name": "Weight", "value": "30" }, { "name": "Calories", "value": "250" } ] } ]'

SELECT i.id, i.fruit, v.[name], v.[value]
FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
WITH (
   id int '$.id',
   fruit nvarchar(50) '$.fruit',
   [values] nvarchar(max) '$.values' AS JSON
) AS i
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT *
   FROM OPENJSON(i.[values])
   WITH (
      [name] nvarchar(max) '$.name',
      [value] nvarchar(max) '$.value'
   )
) v
```

Output:

```
id  fruit   name     value
1   orange  Colour   Orange
1   orange  Weight   16
1   orange  Calories 25
23  Banana  Colour   Yellow
23  Banana  Weight   30
23  Banana  Calories 250
```

If you want output with information about color and weight, try this:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
SET @json = N'[ { "id": 1, "fruit": "orange", "values": [ { "name": "Colour", "value": "Orange" }, { "name": "Weight", "value": "16" }, { "name": "Calories", "value": "25" } ] }, { "id": 23, "fruit": "Banana", "values": [ { "name": "Colour", "value": "Yellow" }, { "name": "Weight", "value": "30" }, { "name": "Calories", "value": "250" } ] } ]'

SELECT i.id, i.fruit, v1.[value] AS Colour, v2.[value] AS Weight
FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
WITH (
   id int '$.id',
   fruit nvarchar(50) '$.fruit',
   [values] nvarchar(max) '$.values' AS JSON
) AS i
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT *
   FROM OPENJSON(i.[values])
   WITH (
      [name] nvarchar(max) '$.name',
      [value] nvarchar(max) '$.value'
   )
   WHERE [name] = 'Colour'
) v1 
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT *
   FROM OPENJSON(i.[values])
   WITH (
      [name] nvarchar(max) '$.name',
      [value] nvarchar(max) '$.value'
   )
   WHERE [name] = 'Weight'
) v2
```

Output:

```
id  fruit   Colour  Weight
1   orange  Orange  16
23  Banana  Yellow  30
```

Comment: Many thanks Zhorov, that is reading the data, but not in the structure I'm after. Interesting approach - I'll see if I can get what I want with this until a can extract the required sctucture.

Comment: @Fetchezlavache Updated answer.

Comment: Great thanks. I still can't believe this is the optimum way of doing it but it works...

Comment: @Fetchezlavache I've changed `CROSS APPLY` with `OUTER APPLY` - If you don't have `Colour` or `Weight` in your JSON. Thanks.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Still looking for an alternative as in reality the data isn't about fruit, and I have 20+ name/value pairs.. :D